# cannot replace this character from a variable

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to remove special characters like `’` from filenames

```
set "filename=%filename:’='%"
```

this works from command line but not from a script.

Comment: seems like a Unicode problem. I can't save `’` in an ANSI codepage

Comment: any simple way to add this sort of support for my script?

Comment: I'd recommend to change the codepage to 65001(Unicode UTF-8). Just for the wide-support.

Comment: I knew nothing of this subject but a simple `chcp 65001` before the code did the trick. I was afraid it was gonna be complex. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to finish up, so here's an answer.

---

Change the codepage to a more widely supported codepage, such as Unicode UTF-8. The corresponding codepage ID is `65001`. To change this, simply add:

```
chcp 65001
```

You can add this snippet to anywhere before your set statement.